# Aviary integration in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and trying to integrate Aviary in android studio and I search it on google but finds nothing. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name 'maven.aviary.com'
        url uri("http://maven.aviary.com/repo/release")
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dnuon.aviarydemo"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
    [enter image description here][1]
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.aviary.android.feather.sdk:aviary-sdk:3.4.3.351'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

I think I have missed to add some in gradle file and I tried a lot to find out the solution but didn't find the solution.I am working from the last two days and tried some demos but unable to run it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://developers.aviary.com/docs/android/setup-guide#androidmanifest)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this gradle in your application gradle file first,

```
compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0'
compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk.foundation:auth:0.3.94'
```

Now download adobe creative SDK from this official [link](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/downloads.html) for this first you have to singup there. Then integrate that sdk into your current project as a module. 
Then after you have to make your application class like below:

```
public class App extends Application implements IAviaryClientCredentials {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AdobeCSDKFoundation.initializeCSDKFoundation(getApplicationContext());
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        AdobeAuthManager manager = AdobeAuthManager.sharedAuthManager();
        manager.initWithApplicationContext(App.this);
        try {
            manager.setAuthenticationParameters("YOUR CLIENT ID WILL BE HERE", "YOUR CLIENT SECRET ID WILL BE HERE", null);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getBillingKey() {
        return ""; // leave it blank
    }

    @Override
    public String getClientID() {
        return "YOUR CLIENT ID WILL BE HERE";
    }

    @Override
    public String getClientSecret() {
        return "YOUR CLIENT SECRET ID WILL BE HERE";
    }

}
```

And in your AndroidManifest.xml file you have to include this are,

```
<provider
            android:name="com.aviary.android.feather.sdk.internal.cds.AviaryCdsProvider"
            android:authorities="com.envyis.AviaryCdsProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:process=":aviarycds" />
```

Comment: If you find answer appropriate then mark this answer as appropriate so some other will also approach it. @ShobinKumar